# Flutter nested declarative navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm trying to implement the new, declarative `Navigation` style in a Flutter Material mobile app. I'd like to have multiple pages stacked on top of each other, with the ability to pop pages one-by-one via the Scaffolds back button.

Example: An app has a primary screen listing breakfast ingredients, a detail page for all ingredients, and finally a page that can be opened from the detail page, listing people who liked that particular ingredient. Focusing only on the navigation part, this is the setup:

```
class MainNav extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Navigator(pages: [
        MaterialPage(key: ValueKey("one"), child: AppShell(title: "Breakfast ingredients", content: "Egg, Crispy bacon, beans")),
        MaterialPage(key: ValueKey("two"), child: AppShell(title: "Crispy bacon", content: "It's crispy!")),
        MaterialPage(key: ValueKey("three"), child: AppShell(title: "People who like Crispy bacon", content: "John, Jill")),
      ], onPopPage: (route, result) => route.didPop(result));
}
```

See a bare minimum working version (state management and everything else left out for simplicity): https://dartpad.dev/3d3451aba0f97016ae8c4b86a8b132bb

The navigation pop works as expected: the app starts from the last page defined in the `pages` list, and by clicking the `Scaffold` back button, pages can be popped one by one up to the top level page. So far so good.

Now I'd like to organize widgets so that navigating to the "People who liked..." subpage is not a responsibility of the `MainNav` any more, but rather the responsibility of the ingredient detail page. I introduced an intermediate `Navigation` that pushes the detail page on to the pages stack, and if required, also the "People who liked..." page. Like:

```
class MainNav extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Navigator(pages: [
        MaterialPage(key: ValueKey("one"), child: AppShell(title: "Breakfast ingredients", content: "Egg, Crispy bacon, beans")),
        MaterialPage(key: ValueKey("sub"), child: SubNav())
      ], onPopPage: (route, result) => route.didPop(result));
}

class SubNav extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Navigator(pages: [
    MaterialPage(key: ValueKey("two"), child: AppShell(title: "Crispy bacon", content: "It's crispy!")),
    MaterialPage(key: ValueKey("three"), child: AppShell(title: "People who like Crispy bacon", content: "John, Jill"))
  ], 
  onPopPage: (route, result) => route.didPop(result));
}
```

See live version: https://dartpad.dev/d0c38e2ec443aafc30d9e9f82ef158d9

What happens here is after popping the last page from the list, we're on the "Crispy bacon" page, with no possibility to pop this one and go back to the list of "Breakfast ingredients" page. I'm probably missing something fundamental about navigation context, and this is not the way to implement hierarchical, declarative style navigation.

So the question: how to delegate navigation tasks down the widget hierarchy, only using declarative navigation concepts? Is there any way to create nested `Navigation` widgets and have all their `pages` behave as a single page hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimum working example showing one of the methods that you could use to navigate from the inner `SubNav` widget to the outer `MainNav` widget can be found below:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Nested declarative navigator',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MainNav(),
    );
  }
}

class MainNav extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Navigator(pages: [
        MaterialPage(key: ValueKey("one"), child: AppShell(title: "Breakfast ingredients", content: "Egg, Crispy bacon, beans")),
        MaterialPage(key: ValueKey("sub"), child: SubNav())
      ], onPopPage: (route, result) => route.didPop(result));
}

class SubNav extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Navigator(pages: [
    MaterialPage(key: ValueKey("two"), child: AppShell(title: "Crispy bacon", content: "It's crispy!", leading: BackButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).maybePop()))),
    MaterialPage(key: ValueKey("three"), child: AppShell(title: "People who like Crispy bacon", content: "John, Jill"))
  ], 
  onPopPage: (route, result) => route.didPop(result));
}

class AppShell extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  
  final String content;
  
  final Widget leading;

  const AppShell({Key key, this.title, this.content, this.leading}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
          leading: leading
        ),
        body: Center(child: Text(content)));
  }
}
```

I have added an optional `leading` parameter to the constructor of the `AppShell` widget. This allows us to pass in a `BackButton` widget that we can create ourselves in the `SubNav` widget. The `BackButton` widget has an `onPressed` parameter, which we can use to `maybePop` the `Navigator` created in the `MainNav` widget. This is possible because the `BuildContext` passed into the `build` method of the `SubNav` widget is outside of the inner `Navigator`, hence calling `Navigator.of(context)` inside the `build` method returns the `NavigatorState` of the outer `Navigator` that is created in the `MainNav` widget.